# github branch restriction on personal account

Tags: github

I want to restrict commits to only few collaborators in few branches. I have personal account in github but donot have any facility to do so as that of organisation. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use GitHub's [standard forking workflow](https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/):

- Each collaborator will fork your repository and do their work in their own fork.
- When something is ready to be contributed back to your repository the developer will create a pull request that you will review.
- That code will only be merged into your repository if you approve it and accept the pull request.

In this way you control the code that gets merged into each of your branches.